# Get javascript cookie expiry value in minutes

Tags: javascript, cookies, gettime

I am using js-cookie to set a cookie with a 1 hour expiry like so:

```
const cookieExpiry = new Date( new Date().getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000 );

const newCookie = Cookies.set("apiKey", "apiKeyFakeValue123456", { expires: cookieExpiry });
```

How would I check age of cookie is equal to or greater than 60m?

My best attempt (not even grabbing expiry value from the time it was set!):

```
if (newCookie.getTime >= 60){ return someFunction();}
```

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where do you see `getTime` in the js-cookie documentation?

Comment: `newCookie` is a string, not an object. You need to parse it to get the expiration time.

Comment: Why do you need to get the expiration time from the cookie? You have it in the variable `cookieExpiry`.

Comment: @Barmar I am trying to create that if a user returns later within 60m, the session is still valid, otherwise they have to log in again

Comment: You can't get the expiration time of a cookie when you return to the page.

Comment: With getTime, I am just trying to show my best understanding of js cookies

Comment: If the user returns after 60 minutes, the cookie will be gone.

Comment: Cookies expire automatically. Just check whether the cookie exists.

Comment: Ahhhh I see now, so I could simply do 
if (apiKey) {return something}

Comment: `if (Cookies.get("apiKey"))`

Comment: How can I buy you a virtual pint of beer my friend? :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barmar answered the question with:
if (Cookies.get("apiKey"))